# Complex bibliography setup

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

I cite some things in footnotes, and want to cite some other things in bibliography using a numbered style. I have to use `biblatex-gost` style, and it provides the functionality.

But I get issue: bibliography counter doesn't start with 1. I tried to reset it using solutions found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66829/count-number-of-references-using-biblatex). But it doesn't work. Neither

```
\usepackage[
...
defernumbers=true,
...
]{biblatex}

...

\printbibliography[resetnumbers=true, notkeyword=footcited]
```

works.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

% Russian/English document:
\usepackage{xecyr}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmainlanguage{russian} % \setdefaultlanguage{russian} is obsolete and not needed
\setotherlanguage[variant=american]{english}

% bibliography:
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    minnames=3,
    citestyle=gost-footnote-min,
    bibstyle=gost-numeric-min,
    url=false,
    sorting=none,
    language=auto,
    babel=other,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  keywords = {footcited},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Text\footcite{A01}.

\nocite{B02, C03}

% bibliography:
\printbibliography[notkeyword=footcited]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

**Edit**:

No Russian, no `biblatex-gost` MWE with `resetnumbers`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\setmainlanguage{english} % \setdefaultlanguage{russian} is obsolete and not needed

% bibliography:
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    minnames=3,
    url=false,
    sorting=none,
    language=auto,
    babel=other,
    defernumbers=true,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  keywords = {footcited},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Text\footcite{A01}.

\nocite{B02, C03}

% bibliography:
\printbibliography[resetnumbers=true, notkeyword=footcited]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Removing the Russian language stuff (which won't compile on my machine) I get the correct behaviour with the extra options you suggest at the top of your question.  However, you have to run xelatex on this a couple of extra times.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: I posted no Russian, no `biblatex-gost` MWE with `resetnumbers`. Does it work on Your machine?

Comment: Yes this version runs fine for me using `xelatex`, `biber`, `xelatex`, `xelatex`.  Note that subsequently you need two runs of `xelatex`; after one, the numbering is wrong and the log file contains the warning `Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.`, after that second run the number is again correct.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: You right: I just have to debug my [tex running script](https://github.com/bk322/bk_TeXs/blob/master/bk_XeLaTeXs.bash). Works for `biblatex-gost` as well.

Comment: In that case, I think we should close this as too localised.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: I agree.