# How can one count the number of cited bibtex entries of a given type?

Tags: bibtex, counters

How does one print the number of cited entries of type "@inproceedings", of type "@article", etc.

E.g., There are \ref{articlecounter} Journal articles.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What might be a use case for your question?

Comment: Would using `biblatex` be an option? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66829/count-number-of-references-using-biblatex

Comment: A use case would be to split the articles in a CV by journal articles, conference articles, workshop articles, etc., and print their numbers.