# LaTeX, biblatex, count literature references

Tags: biblatex, luatex

Sorry for the bad English. I am using `biblatex-gost (+biber)` in my project. I need to count the number of references to literature in the document. What command can I use to do this?

Here is the structure of the document:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = lualatex
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[a4paper,14pt, oneside]{extarticle}
\input{style/NIRS_3_1.sty}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}} 
\makeatother

\setcounter{page}{4}

\usepackage[xindy={glsnumbers=false}, nonumberlist, nopostdot, nogroupskip, toc, translate=babel, acronym, automake]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra, glossary-longbooktabs}

\makeglossaries

\addto\captionsrussian{%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{ТЕРМИНЫ И ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ}%
}
\begin{document}
\input{parts/Referat.tex} % This file contains general information about the document: an abstract, how many tables, figures, and how many references

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\normalsize\bfseries\centering СОДЕРЖАНИЕ}

\tableofcontents
\normalsize
\newpage
    
\input{parts/Glossary.tex}
\input{parts/Acronims.tex}
\input{parts/01_Intro.tex}
\input{parts/02_Bio_sys.tex}
\input{parts/03_Bio_devices.tex}
\input{parts/04_Bio_atak.tex}
\input{parts/05_Outro.tex}

\newpage
\makeatletter

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{СПИСОК ИСПОЛЬЗОВАННЫХ ИСТОЧНИКОВ} 
\makeatother

\printbibliography[title={СПИСОК ИСПОЛЬЗОВАННЫХ ИСТОЧНИКОВ}]


\end{document}
```

Here is a sample content of the abstract, where "????" should count the number of literary sources:

```
\section*{РЕФЕРАТ}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
        \begin{center}
            Отчёт на \pageref{LastPage} с., \totalfigures\ рис., \totaltables\ табл., ??????? ист., Х прил.\\
            
            \textbf{ИНФОРМАЦИОННАЯ БЕЗОПАСНОСТЬ},\\
            \textbf{БИОМЕТРИЯ}, \textbf{БИОМЕТРИЧЕСКОЕ ПРЕДЪЯВЛЕНИЕ},\\
            \textbf{ИНСТРУМЕНТ АТАКИ}, \textbf{АРТЕФАКТ}
     \end{center}       
\pagebreak
```

When using BibTeX, I used the following construction:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Подсчёт количества источников  литературы для реферата %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{numrefs}

\let\bibtemorig=\bibtem
\def\bibtem{\refstepcounter{numrefs}\bibtemorig}

\let\thebibliographyorig=\thebibliography
\let\endthebibliographyorig=\endthebibliography

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}{\thebibliographyorig}{\label{lastref}\endthebibliographyorig}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

And got the number of sources by the command `\ref{lastref}`.

[This document should yield 58 sources:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBPWf.png)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66829/count-number-of-references-using-biblatex

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count all citations in the abstract, you could do something like the following. It actually counts all citations, but if you print the value at the end of the abstract and there are no citations before the abstract, you get the number of cites in the abstract. (If there are citations before the abstract, reset the counter at the beginning of the abstract.)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=gost-numeric, citetracker]{biblatex}

\newcounter{abstractcites}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\stepcounter{abstractcites}}
    {}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum,sigfridsson}

\theabstractcites{} citation(s) in abstract
\end{abstract}

Ipsum dolor \autocite{worman}
sit \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you only want to count unique citations, add an `\ifciteseen`. Again, this assumes that there were no citations before the abstract.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=gost-numeric, citetracker]{biblatex}

\newcounter{abstractcites}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\ifciteseen{}{\stepcounter{abstractcites}}}
    {}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum,sigfridsson}

\theabstractcites{} citation(s) in abstract
\end{abstract}

Ipsum dolor \autocite{worman}
sit \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I explained incorrectly.The abstract is a separate file, which I import with the `input` command. I need to count references throughout the document to correctly generate information on the document: the number of pages, the number of figures and tables and the number of references.

Comment: @Mr_B00k Mhhh, I still don't understand. Maybe you can edit your question and explain what you need and your setup in more detail together with a short example document.

Comment: added information about the problem